# Difference between mongoose.ObjectId and Schema.Types.ObjectId?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In Mongoose, when defining schema-type as a ObjectId, what is difference between `mongoose.ObjectId` and `Schema.Types.ObjectId`? Are both same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `version 3.x`, both are same, `mongoose.ObjectId` is for backward compatibility with `version 2.x`

Ref: [Documentaion](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.7.x/docs/schematypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

**mongoose.ObjectId !== mongoose.Types.ObjectId**. A **SchemaType** is just a configuration object for Mongoose. An instance of the **mongoose.ObjectId** SchemaType doesn't actually create MongoDB ObjectIds, it is just a configuration for a path in a schema.